# How to get $_POST data from external API - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel.( I'm new in Laravel)

I have to make connection beetween my website and external api(without sending request from my website).

I would like to get a POST data from api to a route.

What I made:

Route/web.php

```
/**
* routes test
*/
Route::any('/photo/test', [
    'uses'  =>  'TestController@show',
    'as'    =>  'test.show'
]);
```

Controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function show(Request $request)
    {

        var_dump($_GET);
        var_dump($_POST);
        die(1);
    }
}
```

I checked that from api side there is sending POST data but in laravel Superglobal array $_POST and $_GET are empty as we can see it above(in var_dump() functions).

I also added to exeption those route for VerifyCsrfToken:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        "photo/test"
    ];
}
```

But after added to exception, still I have a problem with empty string...

Can anyone help ?

Comment: take a look at guzzle: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: External API must send POST HTTP request.

Comment: @tilz0R I checked that - is ok.

Comment: @Christophvh I read documentation about it. And i could not found anything about - waiting for response on specify route. Only there is something about sending request on url... But i would like to wait for request from external api.

Comment: put a function(){} in your route instead of controller and check $_POST and $_GET  . Another thing is check your laravel log to see if and error loged or not.

Comment: no errors in logs and function(){} returns empty arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `$_GET` and `$_POST` with Laravel instead use the request object:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    dump($request->input());

    die(1);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You my friend but, I have tried it before use $_POST superglobal.  I tried also to use $request->all() method but it's empty too. It's weird...

Comment: @Z.S How are you making the post request to the route?

Comment: I have an account which is giving an option to sending POST request to my website from those api for a test. I'am doing it, in those application is option to give a route for obtain request. So I wrote my website + route ('www.example.com/photo/test'). It's everything ok, becouse if I return some data with var_dump() function in my controller, api can get it. But I don't have any idea how to get those data which is sending from api by $_POST method. When i changed my domain make the same thing on empty project(different from laravel, for example on word press) I have access toPOST

Comment: this not work, i think because from the external form not have the crsf token. 
try: $request->getContent()

Comment: I post JSON and can read with your example succesfully! Thanks